# Send email using Microsoft graph api fails using app only access with "Confidential Client is not supported in Cross Cloud request."

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service

I am developing an azure web app service called emailservice, which is supposed to communicate to a mailbox created in office365 exchange online. Suppose the user account for the mailbox is x @y-domain.com.
The webapp is suppose to retrieve messages form the inbox or send messages. I have decided to use Microsoft graph api for this matter.
To be able to have successful call to graph API, I need to register the app on Azure. I have done that as well. App only access has been given and Mail.ReadWrite and Mail.send permission under graph have been granted by an admin. We are good on the consent side as well. Here is a snapshot of the permissions
[image: app registration permissions]

I use client credential flow (i.e., acquireTokenByClientCredential) to get access token and then the usual fetch call with access token and the message.I then run it on my local machine and get the error below.

- [Nest] 11088  - 03/15/2024, 8:28:04 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Failed to send email:{"error":{"code":"AuthenticationError","message":"AADSTS900382: Confidential Client is not supported in Cross Cloud request.

Do I get this error because I am running the app on my local machine. If so, I thought I can debug it on my local machine and if it passes then I can run it on cloud.
I am not sure if I deploy it to the cloud and it has error, how can I debug it?

Answer (score 0):

withing the code, I had both commercial cloud and gov cloud and that is why it was complaining about cross cloud. When I use one of them only, then it works.